# Is it possible to get Knockout containerless control flow syntax working in Typescript? Typescript is stripping out comment bindings in HTML

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, visual-studio-code

Typescript (Visual code) is stripping out HTML comments on compile and is therefore stripping out containerless control flow syntax in Knockout.

I have if binding in comments in a table e.g.

```
<table data-bind="let:{scores:$root.myScores}">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:$data">
        <tr>
            <!-- ko if:$index()==0-->
            <td data-bind="attr: {'rowspan':$root.scoreTable.length}">[...cell contents]</td>
            <!--  /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:unit-->
            <td class="hierarchy-table-cell unit" 
                data-bind="attr:{'rowspan':unitSpan}">[...cell contents]</td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried using a custom element to attach the if bindings. The conditional bindings work but because it inserts an element between the `<tr>` and the `<td>` it affects the rowspans which are needed for the table to layout properly.

This is a special case but the same would apply to using comment bindings in tables and in `<ul>` etc.

I have tried setting removeComments to false in the tsc config file but this only seems to affect comments in scripts/code and not in HTML. Plus we don't want all comments left in.

Is there a way of escaping the comments so that they don't get stripped out by typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is TypeScript's fault? It doesn't do anything to HTML as far as I know (nor should it, TypeScript's only job is to compile TypeScript to JavaScript).

I know the Webpack HTML loader strips out comments by default, any chance you're using that?

Comment: Thanks. Will look into that.